# jquery select size attribute changes

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to add fixed height to html dropdown and it works only for first change event. How can I make it work every time on dropdown event change? 
[Here is my code](http://jsfiddle.net/ALau4/)

```
$("select#mySelect").on('focus',function(){
$('#mySelect').attr('size','5');
});
$("select#mySelect").on('change',function(){    
$('#mySelect').attr('size','1');
});

<select id="mySelect">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>6</option>
<option>7</option>
<option>8</option>
<option>9</option>
<option>10</option>
<option>11</option>
</select>
```

Comment: So size is remaining as 5?

Comment: it works only for first click. It stops showing size as 5 after second click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `mousedown` event instead of focus because after clicking on a value the select doesn't lost `focus`.

Code mousedown :

```
$("select#mySelect").on('mousedown',function(){
    $('#mySelect').attr('size','5');
});
    $("select#mySelect").on('change',function(){    
    $('#mySelect').attr('size','1');
});
```

If you must use `focus` event the you can use blur event to unfocus select.

Code blur :

```
$("select#mySelect").on('focus',function(){
    $('#mySelect').attr('size','5');
});
$("select#mySelect").on('change',function(){    
    $('#mySelect').attr('size','1');
    $('#mySelect').trigger('blur');
});
```

[Demo mousedown](http://jsfiddle.net/ALau4/2/)

[Demo blur](http://jsfiddle.net/ALau4/4/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to only comes when the select doesn't lose focus and is selected again. To fix this, I'd use something like `mousedown` instead:

```
$("select#mySelect").on('mousedown',function(){
    $('#mySelect').attr('size','5');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ALau4/3/).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work

```
$("select#mySelect").on('focus',function(){
$('#mySelect').attr('size','5');
});
$("select#mySelect").on('change',function(){    
$('#mySelect').attr('size','1');
    $('#mySelect').blur();
});
$("select#mySelect").on('blur',function(){    
$('#mySelect').attr('size','1');
});
```

you need to catch the focus event then set the size to 5 and when you lose focus 'blur' set the size to 1. When the select changes you can force a the loss of focus on the control, but the reason it only works the first time is that you don't do anything when the control loses focus. So to make the above a little neater.

```
var mySelect = $("select#mySelect");
mySelect
.on('focus',function(){
    mySelect.attr('size','5');
})
.on('change',function(){    
    mySelect.blur();
})
.on('blur',function(){    
    mySelect.attr('size','1');
});
```